# A novel about people that can affect others through reading

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a book a few years ago, that can't be more than 10 years old now.

The story of the book was that there were some people that had the power to affect anyone (I think) via book reading, as well as manipulate someone's thoughts to their own like.

The book started when someone inherited a bookshop from one of his parents.

The original book wasn't in English, but in some European language. That's all I can remember right now.

Comment: The "magic relating to reading books aloud" and "non-English European language" reminds me of Inkheart and sequels by Cornelia Funke. But in those the magic is to bring characters out of the book to the real world, not manipulate minds.

Comment: Just to ask clarification, does the "they" in "some people that had the power to affect others where they read a book" refer to the people with the power or the people being affected?

Comment: @Binney I don't think that is the answer. The book I am looking for was a stand alone novel (IIRC)

Comment: @SeanDuggan I updated my question. Some people had a power to read a book a affect other people

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found it on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Library-Shadows-Mikkel-Birkegaard/dp/0552775029); it popped up on *Related to Items You've Viewed*.

It is a book by Danish Author [Mikkel Birkegaard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikkel_Birkegaard) and it is called *Libri di Luca*, or in English *The Library of Shadows*, published in 2007 in Danish and 2009 in English.

From the description on Amazon:

> Imagine that some people have the power to affect your thoughts and
>   feelings when you read, or they read a book to you. They can seduce
>   you with amazing stories, conjure up vividly imagined worlds, but also
>   manipulate you into thinking exactly what they want you to.
>
> When Luca Campelli dies a sudden and violent death, his son Jon
>   inherits his second-hand bookshop, Libri di Luca, in Copenhagen. Jon
>   has not seen his father for twenty years since the mysterious death of
>   his mother.
>
> When Luca's death is followed by an arson attempt on the shop, Jon is
>   forced to explore his family's past. Unbeknown to Jon, the bookshop
>   has for years been hiding a remarkable secret. It is the meeting place
>   of a society of booklovers and readers, who have maintained a
>   tradition of immense power passed down from the days of the great
>   library of ancient Alexandria. Now someone is trying to destroy them,
>   and Jon finds himself in a fight for his life and those of his new
>   friends.